# как реолизовать данную таблицу с C++. Не прошу сразу готового ответа. Словесное обьяснение

Tags: c++

Я сделал верхнюю строку (# x1 x2 f1 f2) через одномерный массив, далее перешел на следующую строку.
Вопрос остальное нужно через отдельные массивы или одним?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include <cstring>
        #include <math.h>
        
        using namespace std;
        int main()
        {
            setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
            string glasnie("AaEeIiOoUuYy"), Username;
            cout << "Введите фамилию " << endl;
            cin >> Username;
            string Name;
            cout << "Введите имя" << endl;
            cin >> Name;
            unsigned a{}, pos = Username.find_first_of(glasnie);
            while (pos != string::npos) 
            {
                ++a;
                pos = Username.find_first_of(glasnie, pos + 1);
            }
            cout <<"a:: Количество гласных букв в фамилии: " << a << endl;
        
        
            int b;
            if (!(Name.length() % 2))
            {
                b = 0;
                cout << "b:: Количество букв имени четно: " << b<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                b = 1;
                cout << "b:: Количество букв имени нечетно: "<<b<<endl;
            }
            
            
            float fam = Username.length();
                float imy=Name.length();
                float c = fam / imy;
        
                printf("c:: Количество букв фамилии/Количество букв имени %.2f\n", c);
        
        
            int d;
            if (!(Name.length() % 2))
            {
                d = 1;
                cout << "d:: Количество букв имени четно: " << d << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                d = 0;
                cout << "d:: Количество букв имени нечетно: " << d << endl;
            }
        
        
            int f1;
            if (!(Username.length() % 2))
            {
                f1 = 0;
                cout << "f1:: Количество букв фамилии четно: " << f1 << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                f1 = 1;
                cout << "f1:: Количество букв фамилии нечетно: " << f1 << endl;
            }
        
            int f2;
            f2 = Username.length();
            cout << "f2:: Количество букв в фамилии: " << f2 << endl;
        
            int g1;
            if (!(Username.length() % 2))
            {
                g1 = 1;
                cout << "g1:: Количество букв фамилии четно: " << g1 << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                g1 = 0;
                cout << "g1:: Количество букв фамилии нечетно: " << g1 << endl;
            }
        
            int g2;
            g2 = Name.length();
            cout << "g2:: Количество букв имени:" << g2 << endl;
        
            int h1;
            h1 = (f2 + a) * b;
            cout << "h1 = (f2 + a) * b = " << h1 << endl;
        
            int h2;
            h2 = (g2 + a) * d;
            cout << "h2 = (g2 + a) * d = " << h2 << endl;
            
            
        
        
        
        
        
            int fleft[10];
            int fright[10];
            int x1, x2;
            cout << "Введите диопозон\nДиопозон от: ";
            cin >> x1;
            cout << "Диопозон до: ";
            cin >> x2;
            printf("Диопозон x=[%d,%d]\n", x1, x2);
            for (int i = 0; i < abs(x1 - x2); i++)
            {
                fleft[i] = a * pow(x1, 2) + b * pow(x1, 3) - c*x1 - d * exp(x1) + f1 * cos(f2 * x1) + g1 * sin(g2 * x1) + h1 * pow(cos(x1), 2) + h2 * pow(sin(x1), 2);
                x1++;
                fright[i]= a * pow(x2, 2) + b * pow(x2, 3) - c*x2 - d * exp(x2) + f1 * cos(f2 * x2) + g1 * sin(g2 * x2) + h1 * pow(cos(x2), 2) + h2 * pow(sin(x2), 2);
                x2++;
            }
            string massive[5] = { "#","x1","x2","f1","f2" };
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                cout << massive[i] << "\t";
            }
            cout << endl;
            int massive1[10] = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
            for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cout << massive1[i] << endl;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cout << fleft[i] << endl;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                cout << fright[i] << endl;
            }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: А как вам самим удобнее? Можно и так, и так. Я бы вообще массив не использовал, только цикл)

Comment: А можно как то одномерный массив выводить не на новой строке, а справа от предыдущего?

Comment: Конечно. Вместо `endl` используйте пробел, только и всего.

Comment: Я имею ввиду вот первый столбец это один массив, второй столбец это уже другой массив.

Comment: Да, для этого вам нужно сначала вывести первые элементы каждого из массивов, потом все вторые элементы и так далее. Делается двойным циклом.